# Retrofit: how can I get the token

Tags: android, retrofit, access-token

I am a new programmer and I wanted to use Retrofit in android for token-based authorization.Therefore I followed a tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/retrofit-a-simple-http-client-for-android-and-java/) and adapted it to my ruby on rails server (in the tutorial it was a php-server). However I dont know where the token is saved in the program or how to get it. It just appears in the android console. I need to decode the token in my android program. However the token just appears in my android console:

```
com.example.programmingknowledge.login D/Retrofit: {"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJuYW1lIjpudWxsLCJlbWFpbCI6ImV4YW1wbGVAbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NzMwMzU1MTF9.bhJABvEgtRISZVJ0DejjEtrGJyXzNV6PO0YGQ71xHRc"}
```

How can I get the token in my android app? Any idea?

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface Interface {

        //This method is used for "POST"
        @FormUrlEncoded
        //@POST("/api.php")
        @POST("/")
        void postData(@Field("method") String method,
                      @Field("email") String username,
                      @Field("password") String password,
                      Callback<ServerResponse> serverResponseCallback);

        //This method is used for "GET"
        //@GET("/api.php")
        @GET("/")
        void getData(@Query("method") String method,
                     @Query("email") String username,
                     @Query("password") String password,
                     Callback<ServerResponse> serverResponseCallback);

    }
```

Here is a code from the communicator i used (updated with method) :

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.squareup.otto.Produce;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;


public class Communicator {
    private static  final String TAG = "Communicator";
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/authenticate";

    public void loginPost(String email, String password){


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        Interface communicatorInterface = restAdapter.create(Interface.class);

 //HERE I PLACED THE METHOD, BUT HOW CAN I GET THE AUTH-TOKEN WITH THIS METHOD? I want to save it somewhere
        communicatorInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(Interface.class, "auth-token");




        Callback<ServerResponse> callback = new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ServerResponse serverResponse, Response response2) {
                if(serverResponse.getResponseCode() == 0){
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceServerEvent(serverResponse));
                }else{
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(serverResponse.getResponseCode(), serverResponse.getMessage()));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error != null ){
                    Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(-200,error.getMessage()));
            }
        };
        communicatorInterface.postData("login", email, password, callback);

    }


    public void loginGet(String email, String password){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        Interface communicatorInterface = restAdapter.create(Interface.class);
        Callback<ServerResponse> callback = new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ServerResponse serverResponse, Response response2) {
                if(serverResponse.getResponseCode() == 0){
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceServerEvent(serverResponse));
                }else{
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(serverResponse.getResponseCode(), serverResponse.getMessage()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error != null ){
                    Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(-200,error.getMessage()));
            }
        };
        communicatorInterface.getData("login", email, password, callback);

    }

    @Produce
    public ServerEvent produceServerEvent(ServerResponse serverResponse) {
        return new ServerEvent(serverResponse);
    }

    @Produce
    public ErrorEvent produceErrorEvent(int errorCode, String errorMsg) {
        return new ErrorEvent(errorCode, errorMsg);
    }
}
```

And here is my ServiceGenerator Class

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://your.api-base.url";

    private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
                }
            });
        }

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at tutorial : https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android

And go to line like that: 

`public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {`

Comment: Thank you, but where in my code can I invoke this method? I posted the communicator code in my post. Somewhere there?

Comment: Just place methods into your class, these will be called by authorizatizing after login.

Comment: hm I dont get it, this method returns nothing back, how can I get this token? See update in my post where I placed the method createService

Comment: I just want in my code this: String auth_token = .................. Then i can decode (auth_token). But I dont know how I can do this with the method: public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {

Answer (score 0):

retrofit logs json result returned from server ...
as you can see , the token has returned from the server you just need to get it.it should be in ServerResponse Object (If you named the parameters correctly) you can get token by getting **response body**.just save it in a static variable or something then use it in your `createService` method